# Test for Primality Proof Verification

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Question: Prove this:

> [image: this]

Here is my attempt

> [image: This]

I'd appreciate any feedback on my solution, and other ways to go about it. And excuse me for not knowing how to use LaTex.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws for MathJaX help see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

There are some pretty major flaws here; the first is when you try to approach it by cases. you have to show that for all p, at least one proposition doesn't hold, but in each case it sounds like you're only trying to show that there are p for which each particular proposition doesn't hold. also, you assign particular values to n or p, but your proof should hold for all n.

Comment: and there are 7 cases, as with and, if any fail the whole thing does. okay yes they equate to three with symmetry.